How to fine-tune pre-tuned CodeGen Model in Vertex AI
I want to fine-tune the model which is already fine-tuned using code generation model "code-bison".
The existing tuned model is saved into Vertex AI model registry. But I want to fine-tune the model again with my new dataset. I want to know about the efficient way of that process.
Also I looked at the versioning but it's not working for my problem.
Here's my code to fine tune the model first time:
from vertexai.language_models import CodeGenerationModel

training_data = "gs://training/sample_data.jsonl"

model = CodeGenerationModel.from_pretrained("code-bison@002")
model = model.tune_model(
    training_data=training_data,
    train_steps=100,
    tuning_job_location="<LOCATION>",
    tuned_model_location="<LOCATION>",
    model_display_name="custom-code-gen-model",
    accelerator_type="GPU",
)

Then the model exists in the vertex AI model registry. I want to fetch the saved model from there to fine-tune the custom model "custom-code-gen-model" again using the same process of fine-tuning. Instead of using "code-bison@002", I want to use my fine-tuned model "custom-code-gen-model" for tuning 2nd time.
If it is possible to use versioning when it will save the model with same name "custom-code-gen-model", then my problem will be solved also in another way.

Assuming you are trying to achieve chaining supervised tuning, it is not possible to fine tune on top of another custom model. What you might be able to do is to add another model to your deployed vertex model endpoint, and route the traffic between the existing custom model and the new trained custom model. But the supervised tuning will happen with a foundation model (code-bison@002 in your case).

@GangChen Thank you for the information. If I can control the versioning provided by the gcp vertex ai then I can resolve in another way. Whenever I fine-tune the model by providing same model name, it creates duplicate model. But I don't want to create duplicate model either.

Hi @Anis Rafid, did you check this codelabs ? let me know if this helps you or not.

@DhirajSingh Hi. Already checked it and went through most of the official docs.

Hi @Anis, Could you go through his documentation where the process is described regarding fine-tuning the existing fine-tuned models ? Let me know if this helps you or not.

Hello @DhirajSingh. I went through that before.

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
